# Javascript - Separating array values with line break (not commas)?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How can I be able to separate my array values with line breaks rather than commas?

It looks like this now: `apples,bananas,carrots`

I want it to look like this:

```
apples
bananas
carrots
```

This is my code:

```
function insertItem () {

  groceryList.push (foodInput.value);
  groceryList.toString();

  for (var i = 0; i < groceryList.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("printedList").innerHTML = groceryList;
  }

  foodInput.value = "";

}

function deleteItem () {
  groceryList.splice(1,0);
  document.getElementById("printedList").innerHTML = groceryList;
}
```

Comment: Use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on your array: `groceryList.join("\n");` (or possibly `groceryList.join('<br/>');`).

Comment: Why not use more structured HTML, like `<ul>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `groceryList` is the array you are trying to print. If all you're doing is printing the list in a DOM element, you could do this:

`document.getElementById("printedList").innerHTML = groceryList.join('<br/>');`

Comment: sorry, yes -- groceryList is my array.  Your suggestion worked like a charm! THANKS!!